# Get EasyMock to throw an exception during a Retry call

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, easymock, spring-retry

I am attempting to write a unit test which throws an exception on a RetryTemplate that I have mocked. The current test fails on my assertion.

```
/**
     * Test maybeSendNotification() IOException.
     */
    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void testMaybeSendNotificationIOException() throws IOException
    {
        Instance instance = new Instance();
        instance.setState(new InstanceState().withName("DOWN"));
        instance.setKeyName("prod");

        EasyMock.expect(slackMessageSender.send(EasyMock.isA(HashMap.class))).andThrow(new RuntimeException());

        EasyMock.replay(slackMessageSender);
        assertFalse(instanceService.maybeSendNotification(instance));
        EasyMock.verify(slackMessageSender);
    }
```

`slackMessageSender` and `retryTemplate` are both mocks.

This is the method under test:

```
    boolean maybeSendNotification(Instance newInstance)
        {
            Map<String, String> context = new HashMap<String, String>();
            context.put("message", format("Instance with ID '%s' for load balancer '%s' status is DOWN.",
                    newInstance.getInstanceId(),
                    newInstance.getKeyName()));

            try
            {
                retryTemplate.execute( c -> slackMessageSender.send(context));
                LOG.debug(String.format("Successfully sent Slack notification for instance '%s'.", newInstance.getInstanceId()));
                return true;
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                LOG.debug(String.format("Failed to send Slack notification for instance '%s'.", newInstance.getInstanceId()));
                return false;
}
```

Currently the method returns `true` but I would like to get it to throw the IOException and return false. How do I mock this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the retry template is doing but the code seems alright. However, you seem to want to do `EasyMock.expect(slackMessageSender.send(EasyMock.isA(HashMap.class))).andThrow(new IOException());` no?

And if you want to throw an exception for every retry, you will want `EasyMock.expect(slackMessageSender.send(EasyMock.isA(HashMap.class))).andStubThrow(new IOException());`

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that `retryTemplate` is also a mock I would assume that currently the `slackMessageSender.send` method is never executed in the test because the callback of `retryTemplate.execute` is not called.
I think you need to setup the retryTemplate mock to execute its parameter. Something like:

```
EasyMock.expect(retryTemplate.execute).andAnswer(() -> {
    final RetryCallback retryCallback = (RetryCallback) getCurrentArguments()[0];
    return retryCallback.doWithRetry(context);
});
EasyMock.replay(retryTemplate);
```

Also note that with `@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)` the line `EasyMock.verify(slackMessageSender);` would never be executed and the `slackMessageSender` mock never verified because the code will exit when the exception is thrown.

With jUnit 5 you would be able to do something like:

```
EasyMock.replay(slackMessageSender);
IOException exception = assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> {
    assertFalse(instanceService.maybeSendNotification(instance));
});
EasyMock.verify(slackMessageSender);
```